This function has no saddle points: correctness of this reasoning
I would like to know if my reasoning is correct. I have the function $f(x, y) = e^{3x}(1+25x^2+25y^2)$ and I have to study the stationary points.
After computing the gradient I found
$$\begin{cases} 3 e^{3 x} \left(25 x^2+25 y^2+1\right)+50 e^{3 x} x = 0 \\ 50 e^{3 x} y = 0 \end{cases}$$
the only two points I found are $(-3/5, 0)$ and $(-1/15, 0)$.
Now instead of calculating the tedious Hessian, I thought of this: the function is stictly positive, it's unbounded above but bounded below (thought there is no min).
For those reasons, the stationary points cannot be global, and cannot be saddle (because $f$ is strictly positive everywhere).
So the two points are local max and or min.
I wanted to arrive to a conclusion without using the Hessian matrix. But here I got stuck because $1.$ I don't know if what I thought so far is correct and $2.$ I don't know how to go on from here, if possible.
Any hint?

In desmos you can clearly see the saddle point at $(-3/5,0),.$

Define $g(x)=e^{3x}(1+25x^2)$.
You can easily check that $$g'(-1/15)=0,\quad g''(-1/15)>0$$
so  $x=-1/15$ is a local minimum of $g$.
Therefore, in some neighbourhood of $(-1/15,0)$ we will have $$f(x,y)=e^{3x}(1+25x^2+25y^2)\geq e^{3x}(1+25x^2)=g(x)\geq g(-1/15)=f(-1/15,0)$$
so that $(-1/15,0)$ is a minimum of $f$.
Similarly, you can find that $x=-3/5$ is a maximum of $g$.
Therefore, when $x$ is sufficiently near to $-3/5$ we get $$f(x,0)=g(x)\leq g(-3/5)=f(-3/5,0)$$
And by fixing $x$ and moving $y$ we get $$f(-3/5,y)\geq g(-3/5)=f(-3/5,0)$$
so that $(-3/5,0)$ must be a saddle point.

Ahh, so this proves my reasoning about saddle was wrong.. thank you!

I take advantage to ask this too: I'm searching max and min over the set $9x^2 + 9y^2 \leq 1$. I thought I could find both global max and min because of Weierstrass theorem, but I only was able to find the global max. Any other hint for this?

I would recommend using Lagrange multipliers

Ah also: why do you say that $-3/5$ is a max, but then you say it's a saddle?

$-3/5$ is a max for the univariate function $g$, $(-3/5,0)$ is a saddle for the bivariate function $f$.

Ah, sorry. I misread...
